# Java web application deployment Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, web, web-deployment

I was doing some research last time about web services that could provide build & deployment of my Java web application. I found Heroku which seemed to be okay but I encountered some problem.

First of all, my application uses Spring MVC (not Spring Boot), I have manual java-based annotation configuration without web.xml at all. That's about setup. Now when it comes to mentioned error, I connected Heroku with my GitHub repository, then deployed it. Everything built fine with one single problem at the end which looks following:

```
2018-03-23T07:12:02.679019+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Main method not found in class th.config.MyWebAppInitializer, please define the main method as:
2018-03-23T07:12:02.679037+00:00 app[web.1]: public static void main(String[] args)
2018-03-23T07:12:02.679150+00:00 app[web.1]: or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Apparently Heroku environment requires a class that contains main method, which does not exist in my application, at least not in my own code, but probably somewhere in class that runs servlets, like `ServletInitializer` or something like that. I tried to use flag `<skipMain>true</skipMain>` flag in order to skip this but without any luck.

Here I include my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
....
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipMain>true</skipMain>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-war</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipMain>true</skipMain>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0.22.3</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<groupId>webofficesuite</groupId>
<artifactId>webofficesuite</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<!-- SPRING COMPONENTS -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.55</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    ...Other dependencies

</dependencies>
```

I would appreciate any help or guide that would allow me to successfully deploy my app. Additionally I tried other web service that is called OpenShift and I managed to deploy my application there, but I don't like that it is hardly possible to remotely connect to a mysql database, so I would prefer the Heroku solution. But if there are any other good web service hostings that you would recommend I am open for suggestions. The only requirement is that it doesn't cost ridiculously much money per month because it won't be huge application that require a lot of cores and memory.

Comment: Show us your `Procfile`. Also, what command do you use to run the app locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `Procfile` contains something like this:

```
web: java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

You can learn more about using Webapp Runner in the Heroku documentation on [Deploying Tomcat-based Java Web Applications with Webapp Runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner)

Comment: Actually using this procfile with webapp runner helped so that I managed to go through. Thank you